# How Use Bulma Page Loader?

Tags: php, bulma

I am just trying to use bulma framework. I am very impressed with bulma Page-Loader. I have this code than how I can apply it with condition if page on loading Bulma Page-Loader will active. Please give me some tutorial to use this.

```
<?php include 'Include/Head.php'; ?>
<body>
    <div class="pageloader is-black"></div>
    <?php include 'Include/Header.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to use bulma pageloader with seeing implementation on [css ninja](https://cssninja.io/). Thank for css ninja. This how to us bulma pageloader:

1. Add bulma-pageloader.min.css and Jquery
2. Add class pageloader and infraloader [pageloader and infraloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YNRD.png)
3. Add this [code.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpvPd.png)

I dont know if this will help or not. I just wanna share it, cause i'm newbie and spent a lot time to find how it work.